# How to check if an object property is undefined without a for in loop?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function,

```
const doSomething = (a : String, b : Object) => {
  const something = 'something';

  if (!a) {
    throw new Error(
      'a is missing'
    );
  }

  for (let prop in b) {
    if (b[prop] === undefined) { // erroneously previously if (!b[prop])
      throw new Error(
        `prop ${prop} in b is missing`
      );
    }
  }

  return something;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the for..in loop, and somehow check for an undefined property in `b` without it?

Something like,

```
const doSomething = (a : String, b : Object) => {
  const something = 'something';

  if (!a || Object.values(b.includes(undefined))) {
    throw new Error(
      `${!a ? 'a is missing' : 'b contains undefined'}`
    );
  }

  return something;
}
```

But ideally I'd like something a little cleaner and to know the actual undefined prop.

Comment: When you say undefined property you mean a property with value undefined or an undeclared property in b?

Comment: A property with value undefined.

Comment: `if (!b[prop]) { // throw }` - did you *really* mean to treat anything falsy as undefined, or is this a lack of understanding of how to check for undefined properly?

Comment: I meant `if (b[prop] === undefined)`, that was a typo on my part. Or are you suggesting `if (b[prop] === undefined)` is not the same thing as `if (typeof b[prop] === 'undefined')`, as indicated in your answer?

Comment: @MikeK both do the same. Either check the value for `undefined` or check the `typeof value` for the string `"undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'val',
  b: undefined
};

Object.keys(obj)
  .forEach(key => {
    if(!obj[key]) {
      throw new Error(`prop ${key} has undefined value`)
    }
  });
```

--Edit--

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'val',
  b: false
};

Object.keys(obj)
  .forEach(key => {
    if(!obj[key]) {
      throw new Error(`prop ${key} has undefined value`)
    }
  });
```

If only `undefined` case needs to be handled, then you achieve it by using `obj[key] == undefined`.

Comment: I should have clarified, a property with value undefined, not b itself being undefined.

Comment: @MikeK - It is indeed checking for prop `value`.

Comment: what happens when the value of `obj[prop]` is boolean `false`? Hint: You cant use falsyness here, you need to check for actual `undefined`.

Comment: @Jamiec - See edit. If the prop has `0, null, false, undefined`, all of them will evaluate to false.

Comment: Yes, your edit shows a `false` as undefined. Exactly as I expected. And probably not what the OP wanted!

Comment: you should check for `if(obj[key] === undefined)` other than that I think the answer is good, can't understand the downvote

Comment: @randomguy04 - Thanks. Edited the answer. I'am not really sure if the OP wants to handle only `undefined` case or all falsy values like `0, null` etx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Array.some` to determine if any property is undefined

```
function hasUndefinedValue(obj){
   return Object.entries(obj).some(e => typeof e[1] === 'undefined');
}
```

Example below has a few test cases.

```js
function hasUndefinedValue(obj){
   return Object.entries(obj).some(e => typeof e[1] === 'undefined');
}

var tests = [
  {a:"foo"},
  {a:"foo", b: undefined},
  {a:"foo",b:[1,2,3]}
];

for(var i = 0;i<tests.length;i++){
    console.log(tests[i],hasUndefinedValue(tests[i]));
}
```